# Sort answer chaining questions by newest by default

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-deferred, answer-chaining

[answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining)-tagged questions should be sorted newest to oldest by default. It is disorienting to see them out of order because they are sorted highest to lowest votes. Agreed?

Comment: So the answers I should be looking at would be on the last page? That's the opposite of helpful.

Comment: @Dennis I meant newest. Fixed.

Comment: *Newest* would be nice for this. Unfortunately, that option doesn't even exist at this point. The closest match is *active*, but if an answer is edited, it still disturbs the order.

Comment: @Dennis opposite of helpful, and the only foolproof alternative, unless SE decides to add a _newest_ option. Sorting by votes or activity is shooting yourself in the foot. What if the answers number _7,8,9_ are edited after number 10 is posted. (I know you know this, but I'd just mention it in the comments anyway). Sorting by oldest is basically the only way unfortunately. Luckily it's possible to jump to the last page with answers, and scroll to the bottom quite easily.

Comment: @Dennis Actually that's not the opposite of helpful, it's easy to go to the last page, and then you just scroll down. If you have >=2k rep, then there is a different method: search for `inquestion:<question_id>` (`inquestion:<question_id> is:a` if you want to filter the question itself out) and sort by newest. Click the 1st result.

Comment: As per how PPCG works, I would advise that, in general, you sort answers by active just so everyone's answer gets roughly equal exposure

Comment: I am marking this as [meta-tag:status-deferred] because this would be nice, but likely won't happen, at least not soon, due to requiring dev work. This will likely become [meta-tag:status-declined] sometime in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible I'm afraid, unless SE decides to add that feature network-wide. PPCG is a small community compared to SO, SU and the like, so I think we'll have a hard time convincing the developers (and everyone else) that this is something they should spend their time on.

Until then:

**The only foolproof way to sort a [answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) challenge is by *Oldest*, and scroll to the bottom of the last page. It's not that much work.**

Please do not sort by "Activity", that might result in you missing the latest post, creating a lot of work for you and potentially others that base their work on your answer.

Comment: And what about deleted answers? It could be lots of pagebacks before you find the newest non-deleted answer.

Comment: Also, PPCG isn't even a standard Q&A community (except [tag:tips] questions).